# Allow docker container to access the internet

Tags: docker

I would like my app inside docker to have access to the whole internet via host-machine.

I know that I can add particular ip `--add-host=docker:10.6.210.32` But how can I add everything?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use --net=host in docker run command

```
docker run --net=host -it ubuntu
```

Else add dns in config file in /etc/default/docker

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 208.67.222.222 --dns 208.67.220.220"
```

for more info refer:
http://odino.org/cannot-connect-to-the-internet-from-your-docker-containers/

Comment: Thanks for answer! When I run `--net=host -p 6060:8091` parameters together it stops forwarding 8091 port content to 6060 host-machine port.

Comment: When you use --net=host it tells the container to use the hosts network. So you can't expose ports to the host.
else use dns option in DOCKER_OPTS to avoid host network

Comment: And for windows? Which path do I have to use? Instead of /etc/default/docker?